# In Elastic search ,how to get "-id" value of a document by providing unique content present in the document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have few documents ingested in Elastic search. A sample document is as below.

```
                "_index": "author_index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "cOPf2wrYBik0KF", --Automatically generated by Elastic search after ingestion
                "_score": 0.13956004,
                "_source": {
                         "author_data": {
                                  "author": "xyz"
                                  "author_id": "123" -- This is unique id for each document 
                                  "publish_year" : "2016"
                     }
                       }
```

Is there a way to get the auto-generated _id by sending author_id from High-level Rest Client?

I tried researching solutions.But all the solutions are only fetching the document using _id. But I need the reverse operation.

Actual Output expected: cOPf2wrYBik0KF

Comment: Could you share what programming language do you use?

Comment: Get it from hits response, let us know your what language then we can help you easily

Comment: I am using Java

Answer (score 1):

The SearchHit provides access to basic information like index, document ID and score of each search hit, so with Search API you can do it this way on Java,

```
String index = hit.getIndex();
String id = hit.Id() ;
```

OR something like this,

```
SearchResponse searchResponse =  
client.prepareSearch().setQuery(matchAllQuery()).get();
for (SearchHit hit : searchResponse.getHits()) {
  String yourId = hit.id();
}
```

**SEE HERE**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search.html#java-rest-high-search-response

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But I may have more than 500 documents in index. I cannot fetch all document id's to check one particular id. Is there a way to fetch only one id by using match query builders.

Comment: Yes it possible just do a simple Google for that. See

Answer (score 0):

You can use source filtering.You can turn off _source retrieval as you are interested in just the _id.The **_source** accepts one or more wildcard patterns to control what parts of the _source should be returned.(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/search-request-source-filtering.html):

```
GET /author_index
{
  "_source" : false,
  "query" : {
    "term" : { "author_data.author_id" : "123" }
  }
}
```

Another approach will also give for the _id for the search.The stored_fields parameter is about fields that are explicitly marked as stored in the mapping, which is off by default and generally not recommended:

```
GET /author_index
{
  "stored_fields" : ["author_data.author_id", "_id"],
  "query" : {
    "term" : { "author_data.author_id" : "123" }
  }
}
```

Output for both above queries:

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "author_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "cOPf2wrYBik0KF",
    "_score" : 6.4966354
  }
```

More details here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/search-request-stored-fields.html